# Restart .bat file every 12 hours

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

i have a batch file on my server desktop called `start.exe`. I'd like to kill `start.exe` every 12 hours, than wait 2 seconds, and than restart `start.exe`. This should of course also work when no user is logged in on the server. So the workflow should be like:

- Starting Windows Server
- Starting start.exe
- Restart every 12 hours

How can i achive this? With a script? With a task?

Comment: Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler

Answer (score -1):

Run shutdown.exe in a scheduled task set to run every 12 hours. At a command prompt, type shutdown /? to see the options.